# Azure Kubernetes Service deployed app throws com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage-account, azure-aks

I have a simple Spring boot app that connects to an Azure storage account with account key and checks for blob exists. The storage account is protected by "Selected networks" from Networking tab.

The app is working fine in my local after adding my local client IP to the storage account's Firewall whitelist.

After deploying this spring boot app in Azure Kubernetes Service, I'm getting the below exception at `blob.exists()`, even after whitelisting the Kubernetes service IP in storage account's firewall.

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:2073)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:2060)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.exists(CloudBlob.java:2035)
```

I confirmed my Kubernetes outgoing IP [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress#verify-egress-address)

I confirm this error with more than one storage account. Let me know if I'm missing anything on the AKS setup or somewhere else. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your storage account --> Select Networking --> Add your AKS VMSS virtual network

[image]

Now, you would be able to connect to the storage account from the spring boot app

Comment: Yes, I tried this and its working. But why isn't the IP whitelisting technique is not working? Thanks.

Comment: May be the reason is mentioned as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range

Comment: As both the AKS and Storage account are in the same region, the traffic is handled internally in the region itself and never leaves the network via the outbound public IP